# DynamoDB : Get from the last N Records filtered by partition key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm new on dynamoDB. I want get latest N records from table.

My table, `ChatData` has `roomNo` as partition key and `seq` as sort key.

- Table `ChatData` stores chat messages.
- `roomNo` is chat room's number. It is not unique.
- `seq` is a sequential number, for giving unique value each message

Then, I want to get latest message specific roomNo.

For example, 20 chat rooms exists(1 form 20). And 100 messages allover rooms(seq from 1 to 100).
In this case how can I get latest 10 messages related 4th chat rooom using JAVA SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved. 
I used `QueryMapper` and `queryPage` method.

Maybe there are many people stucked into similar question, so I upload my code snippets.

```
        ChatDataDemo demo = new ChatDataDemo();
        demo.setRoomNo(roomNo);
        DynamoDBQueryExpression<ChatDataDemo> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<ChatDataDemo>()
                .withLimit(limit).withHashKeyValues(demo).withScanIndexForward(false);

        QueryResultPage<ChatDataDemo> items = mapper.queryPage(ChatDataDemo.class,
                queryExpression);



        for (int i = 0; i < items.getResults().size(); i++) {
            ChatDataDemo d = items.getResults().get(i);
            System.out.println(d.getSeq() +" / " +d.getMessage());
        }

        //Maybe need to reverse itemResults using Collection.reverse in next
```